# all my li menu item close the menu not do what they should

Tags: html, css

hello i have made this menu side bar with html and CSS but it have problem that i need help the Li are not responsive the herf "#" is just holding a places for real links the first li in the first ul is not working when i press on it just close the menu and the herf # dont go up the page like it should all the li just close the menu when i press on them

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.dvm {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: left;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.dva1,
.dva2 {
  position: relative;
}

.dva1 ul,
.dva2 ul {
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: last baseline;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform: translate(-10px);
}

.dva1 a,
.dva2 a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left baseline;
  color: maroon;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.dva1 li,
.dva2 li {
  border: black solid 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dva1 li:hover,
.dva2 li:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.dvm button {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: initial;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.dvm button:hover {
  color: rgb(58, 112, 94);
}

.dva1 button:focus + ul,
.dva2 button:focus + ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dvm">
    <button><a target="_blank" href="page.html">Home</a></button>
    <input type="text">
    <button><a target="_blank" href="page.html">Search</a></button>
    <button><a target="_blank" href="page.html">Sign up</a></button>
    <button><a target="_blank" href="page.html">Login</a></button>
    <button><a target="_blank" href="page.html">Home</a></button>
    <div class="dva1">
      <button>menu1</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="news.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dva2">
      <button>menu2</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dva2">
      <button>menu2</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dva2">
      <button>menu3</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="dva2">
        <button>menu4</button>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dva2">
        <button>menu5</button>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these menu items are visible and possible to click only when given button is focused. So if you click the link, button lost his focus and ul is made unclicable again before even redirecting to the page. To fix this you can add  another selector to your css:

```
.dva1 > ul a:focus, .dva2 > ul a:focus{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```